# How can humans seal gods away

Tags: magic, medieval, gods

Let me first explain the gyst of my work in process. It's set in a medieval world where Magic comes in the form of earths natural energy. God-like entities overlook regions around the world and and share traits with their domain such as forests/jungle/deserts/volcano. One of these entities shared their energy with their humans, granting them special gifts albeit at a cost. This trade drains the entities overtime and the energy gets weaker. Some humans seek to control more entities and gain more power.

My problem is coming up with a feasible way that they would achieve this. Ive toyed with the idea of there being some form of trap or restraints such as chains which could be used but where would these come from? How are they used?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider Sun Tsu.  Know yourself; know your enemy.  What are your humans able to do?  What are the gods weak against?  "Gods" is a very wide term, as is "magic."  Pinning down strengths and weaknesses is a first step.

Comment: Seal them away or turn them into poke-gods?

Comment: "Magic" in my world is more like energy, the worlds natural energy. These "gods" keep the balance of energy and control different regions (nature/volcanoes/jungle/desert/mountains). One "god" gave a gift to humans in their region by sharing their "magic". Humans got greedy and sought more power. Thus wanting to control "gods".

Comment: We'd need to know about the mechanics of your magic system and probably your gods as well to be able to answer this question with anything other than wild mass guessing.

Comment: *Some humans seek to control more entities* Do you mean they want to "form contract" with more entities? What exactly are you asking here? How can they seal gods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### They were produced by the god-like entities themselves

They were produced by the god-like entities themselves and stolden by some trickster god // demi-god; out for revenge // to aid humainty // as part of some really complicated plot // just because.

Comment: I do like this idea and believe it could be used

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked the idea behind names.  If you know the *true* name of a god or a demon, you have true power over it.  To be able to determine the name of a god obviously must be something incredibly difficult to achieve, but knowing the name of said god is akin to having all the powers that god can provide.

Of course those with the names of these gods would not have them do as they please, so they trap them in oil lamps or other objects to summon as they please.  In this sense, it isn't the object *itself* that binds them, it is the desire of the one who knows their true name and can't be denied not even when the original namer dies.  So this means gods may be lying in wait in objects because they have no choice.

The type of object could be subject to change, or perhaps the namer simply tells them they cannot pass through iron, and then construct a container of iron, or bind them using chains.  Ultimately it gives you the flexibility to "bind" gods however which way you want, but the source is always the namer with the talent to find the god's true name.

Answer (score 0):

You have it in your question: a medieval world set in magic. Magic is vast and you can play with it to your hearts desire. All you need is great imagination.

Legends could play a good part in it. A legend about a spell in a book, or about some sort of manuscript which can bind the Gods in it by writing their name in their own language with a special pen. Just sit down and imagine these Gods and play with ideas. There are so many ways you can do it. Just imagine.